# How to implement online judge bot?(ex. TopCoder, Uva, ACM-ICPC)

Tags: c++, python, algorithm, sandbox

There are many online judge sites which can verify your program by comparing its output to the correct answers. What's more, they also check the running time and memory usage to make sure that your program doesn't exceed the maximum limit.

So here is my question, since some online judge sites run several test programs at the same time, how do they achieve performance isolation? and how do they achieve same running time on same program that run at another time?

I think there are isolated environment processes like 'VMware' or 'Sandbox' that always return same result. is this correct? and any idea about how to implement these things?

**Current Solution**

I'm using [docker](https://www.docker.com/) for sandboxing. it's a dead simple and the safest way.

Comment: Your question is almost an invitation to an open ended discussion. Try to break it down into several more concrete questions. See: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it is VERY hard to actually guarantee consistent running times even on a dedicated machine versus a VM. If you do want to implement something like this as was mentioned you probably want a VM to keep all the code that will run sandboxed. Usually you don't want to service more than a couple of requests per core so I would say for algorithms that are memory and cpu bound use at most 2 VMs per physical core of the machine.

Although I can only speculate why not try different numbers of VMs per core and see how it performs. Try to aim for about a 90% or higher rate of SLO compliance (or 98-99 if you really need to) and you should be just fine. Again its hard to tell you exactly what to do as a lot of these things require just testing it out and seeing how it does.

Answer (score 0):

May be overly simplistic depending on your other requirements which aren't in the question, but;

If the algorithms are CPU bound, simply running it in an isolated VM (or FreeBSD jail, or...) and using the built-in operating system instrumentation would be the simplest.

(Could be as simple as using the 'time' command in unix and setting memory limits with "limit")

Comment: My service goal is [IDEONE](http://www.ideone.com). it always return same running time and same memory usage. i'll find some VMs you said.Thanks Joachim.